# Eclipse Java content assist not working for files with lambda expressions

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, content-assist

**My question:**

What can I do to prevent content assist from breaking when I write <s>larger</s> files that contain lambda expressions?

**The issue (description):**

For some time now, Eclipse's content assist for Java has stopped working properly for <s>larger</s> files in my IDE when I use lambda expressions. <s>I never encounter the issue when writing smaller files, but when I write files at 1500~2000+ lines of code it is like the content assist suddenly gives in and it becomes unstable.</s> When I activate content assist near the top of the file there are no issues:

[image: content-assist working]

In the above picture, content assist performs exactly as I expect it to. However, when I activate content assist closer to the bottom, it becomes unresponsive (does not activate when I type `.`) and activating it manually with `ctrl + space` brings up an empty list:

[image: content-assist not working]

For this particular file, content assist stops working in any part of the file after line 1540, which is right after a lambda expression. Removing the lambda expression does not solve the issue, but instead propagates it further down the file, to the next lambda expression.

The following message is also displayed in the toolbar when this happens:

[image: toolbar message]

**Things I have tried:**

- Using a clean Eclipse IDE with the existing workspace as well as a new workspace.
- Clearing the index cache in `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core`.
- Enabling all proposal kinds in `Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced`.
- Restoring defaults on the settings page just mentioned above.
- Increasing the amount of memory allocated to the Eclipse IDE in `eclipse.ini` to 2 gigabytes as well as increasing the amount of memory allocated initially to 1 gigabyte.
- Adding `-vmargs -Dorg.eclipse.jdt.ui.codeAssistTimeout=60000` to `eclipse.ini`

**Edit #1**

<s>As mentioned the issue only occurs for larger Java files. Below is a picture of a smaller Java file with 3 different lambda expressions and content assist works as expected:</s> See Edit #2

**Edit #2**

Below is a Java SCF to reproduce the issue. I've tried my best to make it as small as possible. In this case, the issue occurs when using a lambda expression in conjunction with a for-loop, but I imagine it might be possible to reproduce the issue with other control statements as well.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Foo {
    public Foo() {
        foo(() -> {
            final ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (final Object o : list)
                ;
            /* works until here */ } /* no longer working */
        );
    } // <--- content assist works again after end bracket of constructor/method
    void foo(final Runnable r) { r.run(); }
}
```

Notes:

- Enclosing the body of the for loop with curly brackets fixes the issue.
- The issue only occurs with the `for-each` variant of the for loop; using the `for(;;)` variant fixes the issue.

Comment: Which Eclipse version? Please show sample code to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @howlger My current version of Eclipse is 2019-06 (4.12.0). The clean version I used is 2019-12 (4.14.0). Also, I do not know how to provide sample code for this issue, besides the pictures I have provided - this is not an issue with the Java code itself, like a compilation problem or runtime error, but instead with the IDE. I do not think posting the entire file (over 1000 lines of code) is a good idea.

Comment: You can post a link where you have published the file or even better, Java code that generates the Java file to reproduce this issue. Eclipse can handle even much bigger files, so I doubt it is related to the number of lines. Prove that I'm wrong.

Comment: @howlger I think we are talking past each other. This is not an issue with my Java code or this particular Java file. It is an issue I have with the Eclipse IDE in general. When I write larger Java files (many lines) and they contain lambda expressions, content assist stops working at certain parts in the file. See "Edit #1" for a picture of a small sample file (few lines) with lambda expressions, in which content assist does work, for your proof.

Comment: For eclipse to work with lambdas correctly, all other code must be correct (i.e. compilable, no errors) and sometimes unmodified (i.e. changes are saved). Also sometimes in lambda it cannot resolve class name to import, so I have to first import the class, and then use it in lambda.

Comment: I agree with @howlger If you provide a sample java code file that is giving you problems, I can copy it to my machine and see if I can reproduce the same behavior. By the way, have you tried creating a new [Eclipse] workspace? Or do you keep using the same workspace even after installing a new Eclipse version?

Comment: @AdamMartinu Let's stop wasting time with speculation (about when and what is causing this issue and what you think I think). Just show code to reproduces this issue to have something to work with.

Comment: @Abra In the clean Eclipse IDE, I have tried using the original workspace and also creating a new one, yet the issue persisted in both cases. I will work on writing sample code to attempt to reproduce the issue in a single Java source file and post a link to the file when I have finished.

Comment: @howlger I've made a new edit and provided code for a Java SCF to reproduce the issue. I'm sorry it took a while. And you were right. After tinkering a bit, I discovered the size of the file is completely irrelevant! It just so happened that it had never occurred in my smaller files, so I made an assumption... A mistake on my part.

Comment: @Abra I've made a new edit and provided code for a Java SCF to reproduce the issue, I'm sorry it took a while.